# If first tab is hidden make active the first tab that is displayed

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I've got a simple question about jQuery UI Tabs. I have a menu with 6 tabs.
The first tab will always be the "active" one. But in some cases one or more tabs will be in `"display: none;"`. Is there a way to find the first visible tab and apply the active class to that one?

Any help with these will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. Are you asking about tabs or tab panel content? Wouldn't it already have an active class? It would help if you showed some code and/or a demo.

Comment: if a tab is hidden whether both the title and content will be hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the title and the content is hidden then you can use the active option like

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    active: $( "#tabs > ul li:visible" ).first().index()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/171r51ny/)

Comment: Thanks, I think I was needing something like this. I just realized that I've got to hide the first tab content too if the tab will be hidden.